# How to fix warnings okhttp and samsung spass sdk?

Tags: android, warnings, proguard

I am writing an application using okhttp and samsung spass sdk. When I generate apk release using proguard, I get the warnings.

```
Missing class: org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier
Missingclass:com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
Missing class: com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
Missing class: com.samsung.android.fingerprint.IFingerprintClient$Stub
Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int)`
Type `org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$configureTrustManager$1`
```

After a little research, I added a few lines:

```
-dontnote com.samsung.**
-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-keep class com.samsung.** {*;}

-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
```

Two warnings disappeared, but 4 is still there:

```
Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `boolean okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion.atLeastVersion(int, int, int)`
Type `org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$configureTrustManager$1`
Missingclass: com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$EnrollFinishListener
Missing class: com.samsung.android.fingerprint.FingerprintIdentifyDialog$FingerprintListener
```

And so that I did not try it does not help

How could I fix it?

I have already tried some things such as

For samsung spass, I found nothing more.

For okhttp:

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

And it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

> While reading the info message, it gives me an idea about this
> Conscrypt and did a research and found out that I need to install
> conscrypt to my gradle.app

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'
```

and it works.